# PY4E Question -- Exploring the HyperText Transport Protocol

Tags: python

I'm sorry for the basic question, but when I use the following code to retrieve a document:

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))
cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if len(data) < 1:
        break
    print(data.decode(),end='')

mysock.close()
```

What my terminal ends up returning is the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://google.com/
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
```

Why won't it retrieve the file itself?

Comment: This is because the original request is redirected ( `302 found`). You can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 28 Apr 2022 20:20:16 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Sat, 13 May 2017 11:22:22 GMT
ETag: "a7-54f6609245537"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 167
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain

But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief
```

It appears your code is accessing a different url, (presumably, `http://google.com`), and is getting a 302 redirect, asking your browser to try to get `http://google.com/` instead.